# Постоянное соедининие с MySQL

Tags: mysql, timeout

Знаю, что если соединиться с сервером (MySQL) , то есть timeout, после истечения которого соединение закрывается. 
А нужно, что бы не закрывалось никогда, если приложение (например) работает. Можно в принципе поставить значение timeout на очень большое время. Но я полагаю, это не выход.

Можно ли настроить MySQL на постоянное соединение?

В PDO - ATTR_PERSISTENT вроде как включает постоянное соединение. 
У нас Python, ORM peewee. Т.е. если это возможно с PDO , то должно быть возможно и по другому. Да просто настройки MySQL. Разве нет таких?

Comment: А зачем вам вообще понадобился persistent connection? В чем именно ваша настоящая проблема?

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev приложение использует WebSockets. Я думаю разумно не переподключаться к БД, т.к. приложение работает постоянно.

Comment: А если ваше приложение вдруг потеряет соединение с БД (например из-за проблем с сетью)? Будете перезапускать приложение? Ни один метод подключения не может гарантировать 100% отказоустойчивости. Правильнее было бы реагировать на разрывы, восстанавливая соединения. Или, как предлагает @Алексей Присяжный использовать пул соединений

Comment: Хм.. Да, в принципе. Если так на это посмотреть.. Спасибо !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Суть идеи постоянного соединения у PHP - постоянно запущенный процесс PHP просто хранит в общей памяти информацию об установленном соединении. При запросе коннекта отдаёт вместо создания нового - существующий.

В случае с [peewee](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#connection-pooling) тоже есть стандартный механизм:
Connection Pooling
Connection pooling is provided by the pool module, included in the Playhouse, extensions to Peewee extensions library.

The pool supports:

- Timeout after which connections will be recycled.
- Upper bound on the number of open connections.
  The connection pool module comes with support for Postgres and MySQL (though adding support for other databases is trivial).

я бы предложил RTFM :)

Comment: Да, но переподключения то все-равно будут. А мне кажется разумным будет вообще не отключаться. Бессмысленно же. Да, используем WebSockets, приложение постоянно работает.

Comment: Ключевое, зачем используются постоянные соединения - снизить потери времени на переподключение. Если пул сам будет поддерживать открытое подключение или переоткрывать при необходимости - это и будет постоянное соединение. Пинайте хостера, если мускуль медленно коннектится (было такое в практике)

Comment: In a single-threaded application, only one connection will be created. It will be continually recycled until either it exceeds the stale timeout or is closed explicitly (using .manual_close()). - в однопоточном приложении только одно соединение будет открыто и будет постоянно ПЕРЕИСПОЛЬЗОВАТЬСЯ, пока...

Comment: т.е. единственное решение - это пул соединений, получается ? тогда какое значение лучше будет для with_timeout ? максимальное значение вообще есть для него ?

Comment: @Мстислав-Павлов ведь уже ответил. Если перейти по ссылке, то можно видеть, что по умолчанию 8 часов. Если приложение постоянно работает (и будет обновлять время последнего обращения), то таймаут не истечет примерно никогда. Сильно большое время лучше не ставить - если соединение залипнет по какой-то причине, так хотя бы помрёт своей смертью достаточно быстро

Answer (score 1):

Для установки времени ожидания в MySQL используется  параметр `wait_timeout`. Данный параметр нельзя установить на бесконечное ожидание.

Изменить этот параметр можно следующей командой:

```
SET GLOBAL connect_timeout=....;
```

[Документация](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout)

Comment: Ну неужели нельзя не прерывать соединения. Допустим мы используем WebSocket. Запустилось приложение и все. Больше не выключается. А к базой получается нужно переподключаться периодически? В MongoDB такого нет..

Comment: @Akademic по умолчанию время ожидания у БД 8 часов(если память не изменяет). Это время начинает отсчитываться при отсутствии активности.

Comment: т.е. wait_timeout нельзя поставить больше 28800 ?

Comment: @Akademic нет, вы не поняли, это значение по умолчанию. Можно поставить больше. Просто проблема по всей видимости где то в другом месте.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.connections.php - вот тут написано, что можно это сделать при использовании библиотеки PDO, передав в конструктор, 4-м параметром массив, содержащий константу `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT`.

```
<?php
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass, array(
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT
));
?>
```

Comment: А у нас Python. ORM peewee. Но не суть. Если это как-то PDO делает, то, получается, можно и без него сделать?

Comment: @Akademic я так понял, нужно как-то вручную пользоваться пулом соединений.